# Remove limited activity from stack not all

Tags: java, android

I have five activity for example

A, B, C, D, E

I am going from A -> B  -> C -> D -> E

now when i press button from E

i want to go to directly B and **B should not create new actiivity**

I know that

```
    Intent intent  = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);        
    startActivity(intent);
```

by this i can do it but i don't want to create activity B by doing startActivity

Answer (score 0):

In the button's onClick you can have the following:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);        
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: at least properly read  i have clearly told that B should not create new actiivity

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); clears the back stack when you go to ActivityB.

Answer (score 0):

In your application manifest file define the Activity like

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.taskandbackstackexample.BActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_b"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>
```

and start your activity as

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, BActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

The activity's "launchMode" attribute has value "singleTask". The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the activity can exist at a time.